# Is there any way to make some rectangular areas of a mask to be transparent?

Tags: unity-game-engine

I am using UGUI to make a Novice guide to guide people to play my game.

And need the whole UI be mask, but some rectangular areas to be lighted.

How to do?

Answer (score 0):

Create a new gameobject and add a image component to it. Create a image with transparent areas where you want your ui to be visible. Assign that image to the image component. Then add a mask component

Put your other gui elements inside this gameobject so that is could overlap and hide everything except transparent areas. Here is the picture of demo setup. [image]

Answer (score 0):

IMHO, what you want to achieve is not easy to be done perfectly in Unity. Here is my personal solution:

1. I put a black panel below every other GUI, so that it darkens my entire screen.
2. I put an empty game object called BrightRoot below the panel, so that everything under BrightRoot will float over and "brightened".
3. In my tutorial script, I add function to look for a UI game object by name and change its parent to the BrightRoot. In example:

> // To brighten the object
>   GameObject button = GameObject.Find("PlayButton");
>   Tansform oldParent = button.transform.parent;
>   button.transform.SetParent(BrightRoot, true);
>
> // To darken it again
>   button.transform.SetParent(oldParent, true);

The perfect solution would be to write a UI shader that darken any pixel outside some rectangles and brighten the inside. Then set that shader to all UI objects.

**Editted:**

This just another easy method, using UI Vertex effect. Just need to implement IsPointInsideClipRect, put this component to your UI objects, and set the rectangles list:

```
using UnityEngine;
using System.Collections;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using UnityEngine.UI;

[AddComponentMenu("UI/Effects/Clip")]
public class Clip : BaseVertexEffect

{
    // We need list of rectangles here - can be an array of RectTransform
    public RectTransform[] ClipRects;

    public override void ModifyVertices(List<UIVertex> vertexList)
    {
        if (!IsActive())
        {
            return;
        }

        bool isClipped = true;

        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            UIVertex uiVertex = vertexList[i];

            foreach (RectTransform rect in ClipRects)
            {
                if (IsPointInsideClipRect(rect, uiVertex.position)) 
                {
                    isClipped = false;
                    break;
                }
            }           
        }

        Color32 color = isClipped ? new Color32(0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f, 0.5f) : new Color(1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f);
        for (int i = 0; i < count; i++)
        {
            UIVertex uiVertex = vertexList[i];
            uiVertex.color = color;
        }
    }

    private static bool IsPointInsideClipRect(RectTransform rect, Vector3 position)
    {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Comment: What I wanted is the UI shader, I would create a UI object with a transparent image, and then just set the shader to the transparent UI image. Instantiate the transparent UI image when I need. But the shader is the biggest problem. So I choose a stupid method: create a UI object base on whole screne and divide the UI object with many grids via layout component.

Comment: Please review my edited answer. Maybe it would serve your purpose.

Comment: Seems effective, but I'm not very clear how to use it. I add a image component to UI object, and try to let the IsPointInsideClipRect return a true always,  Also try to "uiVertex.color = new Color32(0,0,255,255)". Found nothing, but can output log. Can you explain me what is uiVertex.color? It change the image component's color, or something else color?

Comment: I see.I missed some codes. It change the UI object's 4 Vertices's color. But I also want to change each pixel's color or change a rect's color which is just a part of UI object rect. Thanks for your answer to let me know BaseVertexEffect. I'm a new guy, and didn't know it before.

Comment: BaseVertexEffect only allows changing the 4 vertices of UI objects, so it might not help if you want pixel perfect solution. Going shader is more complicated, and by now, I do not have enough time to experiment. I suggest you upload some mock up screen, so every one can know exactly your need.